# TFS 2018 on Prem, create new State in the board?

Tags: tfs

We are trying to use the XML templates to try and modify our on prem TFS 2018 instance to have more states on the board. Right now we have 3 (To Do, In Progress, Done)

Is this possible to do? We would like to add a 5 State to be something about testing.

If that isn't do-able what do others do in the board and backlog to put a task into a testing state? Add a category called "testing"? there is only "bug" and "product backlog item"

We are struggling because our testing person doesn't know what needs to be tested by looking at the board.

Comment: "Bug" and "Product Backlog Item" are types of work items, not categories. Both types of work items can be customized to have a 'Testing' state. Do you break down your bugs and PBIs into tasks? Another approach is to create Task work items for testing. The testing tasks could be assigned to the testing person.

Comment: Why would testing not be a task underneath the PBI that's part of the definition of done for the PBI?

Answer (score 1):

To add new columns, you may:

1. Add new states to needed work item types: [Change the workflow for a work item type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/change-workflow-wit?view=azure-devops-2022&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops)
2. Add new states to the boards: [Import and export process configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-process-configuration?view=azure-devops-2022), [Map WIT category workflow states to state categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/process-configuration-xml-element?view=azure-devops-2022&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops#map-wit-category-workflow-states-to-state-categories)